# Prevent Oracle schema password expiration

Tags: oracle

There are web applications on top of the database using the Oracle APEX server. How do I prevent the passwords for each schema being expired.

Answer (score 1):

With a statement such as this:

ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;

This will set the password lifetime to unlimited for users with the default profile.
To find out which profile your user is using use this query:

SELECT profile FROM dba_users WHERE username='YOUR_USER';